# How to enter php data into a html multiple select box

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm working on the page that will allow one create a TEAM. I just want to create a SELECT box that will contain the list of ALL the user's friends. Then, the user can select more than one friend (e.g. 5) and send requests to these 5 persons to join  the team but am having problems. I did this:

```
$sql = "SELECT i.*, m.* FROM addclique i JOIN members m ON m.id = i.clique_id WHERE adder_id = :id";
$stmt = $db->query($sql, array('id' => $_SESSION['id']));
while($record = $stmt->fetch()) {
   $surname=$record['surname'];
}
```

And this:

```
<select multiple="true" name="category"  val id="category" name="category" class="">
<option value="<?php echo $surname; ?>"><?php echo $surname; ?></option>
</select>
```

But only the surname of only one friend is entered into the box.
I want to have all the friends in the select box and when I select friends and click 'send request', I can easily get the ids entered into a 'team members' table.

Please what are my missing?

Comment: Sidenote: `val` that shouldn't be in there.

Comment: Also don't forget the <?php tags, likely this page gives errors without them.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it.  All you need to do is loop out the names instead of storing them.

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT i.*, m.* FROM addclique i JOIN members m ON m.id = i.clique_id WHERE adder_id = :id";
    $stmt = $db->query($sql, array('id' => $_SESSION['id']));

?>

<select multiple="true" name="category"  val id="category" name="category" class="">
<?php while($record = $stmt->fetch()) : ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $record['surname']; ?>"><?php echo $record['surname']; ?></option>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</select>
```

For future reference the correct way to store the data from the database would be like this.

```
$stmt = $db->query($sql, array('id' => $_SESSION['id']));
$results = array();
while($record = $stmt->fetch()) {
   $results[]=$record;
}
```

You may want to clean up your query too and just `SELECT surname FROM` if you're not using the other data.  Then you can do this.

```
while($surname = $stmt->fetchCol(0)) {
   //.... and skip the array access altogether
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this :

```
$select = '<select multiple="true" id="category" name="category">';
while($record = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $surname = $record['surname'];
    $select .= '<option value="'.$surname.'">'.$surname.'</option>';
}
$select .= '</select>';

echo $select;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT i.*, m.* FROM addclique i JOIN members m ON m.id = i.clique_id WHERE adder_id = :id";
$stmt = $db->query($sql, array('id' => $_SESSION['id'])); ?>
//SELECT IS OUTSITE 
<select multiple="true" name="category"  val id="category" name="category" class=""> <?php
while($record = $stmt->fetch()) {
   $surname=$record['surname'];
//OPTIONS ARE ADDED IN THE WHILE LOOP 
  ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $surname; ?>"><?php echo $surname; ?></option> <?php
} ?>
</select> // END SELECTION
```

Comment: Just a though you might want to put some <?php tags between the code and html.

Comment: You can set the answer as good with the "V" if it works. Glad I could help